# Get data back from a windows Process to winform

Tags: c#

I'm new here and it's a first time that i ask for help to the community. I'm also new in C sharp but i try to manage and learn on the way.

I would like to have some help to understand how to write a Process for windows with wich i can communicate with my winform.

i made an winform application which permit me to retrive some data from Active directory and also some other data from computers on the network "using powerShell" and a AD class.

For some reasons i can't grab a correct information about ex: shared Printers, cose the PowerShell give me a output of the computer printers, not user printers. It was a simple exemple.

so i decide to write a Process wich i want to upload and install on a remote computer, till here i can manage that.

what i would like to understand and if you can show me a little exemple, it's how to add some functions to this process and get the output of this function back to my Winform.

as exemple:

1.in my Winform a make a remote call to the process and ask him to give me the list of all printers installed.
2. show the output in a lisbox for exemple.

I would like to tell you thank you in advance for you help

Comment: you should look at WCF as an option

Comment: You decided to create a process/service because Powershell did not return the right printers? Maybe you should look into making a different Powershell query instead (one which would return correct results)?